# How can i validated input field with required if checked Checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, html

I have made a shop-billing project with JSP. Here a function has been made if i check a checkbox, the product quantity is required. It is as like as below image. Now how can i implement the text inputs required when i will press the order button if multiple checkboxes have been checked? 
[image]

**Code:**

```
<tr>
     <td><%=rs.getString("id")%></td>
     <td> <input type="checkbox" id="products_check" name="products" value ="<%=rs.getString("id")%>" /> </td>
  <td> <input type="text" id="item_no" name="item_no_<%=rs.getString("id")%>" />        </td>
 <td><%=rs.getString("product_name")%></td>
 <td><%=rs.getString("product_price")%></td>
 <td class="text-center" width="250">
 <a href='edit.jsp?u=<%=rs.getString("id")%>' class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
                            <a href='delete.jsp?d=<%=rs.getString("id")%>' class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you

```
$("input[name='products']").on("change",function(){
  if($(this).prop("checked")){
    $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='text']").prop("required",true);
  }
  else{
    $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='text']").prop("required",false);
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fwq08r49/

Comment: not working brother, it is redirecting to the next page without required option

Comment: are you having dynamic content?

Comment: can you try using $(document).on("change","input[name='products']",function(){ ...
insead of $("input[name='products']").on("change",function(){...

Comment: and let me know if you are getting any console error?

Comment: brother, it is for multiple checkbox, it sometimes working for one, but not for multiple

Comment: it is not working, brother your code only in static

Comment: Can you please provide me HTML for 3-4 rows? So I can look into it? Sorry for the delay

Comment: Just rendered rows. Not from code. If you can using inspect element

Comment: hello, sorry for late, are you there?

Comment: can we go to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196529/discussion-between-nayeem-hyder-riddhi-and-ravi-patel).

Answer (score 0):

You watch for the input to `change` and then get the sibling checkbox over their shared parent.

Example:

```
$(".container").on("change keyup", "input", function(e) {
  var $checkbox = $(this).parents("tr").find("checkbox");

  if ($checkbox.prop("checked") && !this.value.length) {
     alert("Input required.");
  }
});
```

EDIT:
Added keyup event and attaches listener to parent (which is not dynamically replaced and available at runtime) to catch all events.

Comment: when i press order button, it is not showing the required option for input

Comment: Of course you have to adapt the code to your specific requirements and enviroment.
Also not that `change` is only triggered after `blur`ing the field.
As I saw you also have dynamic content, ive made an edit for that.